# Codeigniter AJAX CSRF protection

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, constructor, csrf

I am using codeigniter on the backend .

Recently i heard about the term "CSRF" and decided to protect the requests.

Almost all actions on my site is through Ajax & some times i am creating/appending page content using DOM manipulation [here the doubt, how can i inject the CSRF token to the view files ?]

Okkey ,after that how can i validate that ?

Assume that i added these values as token and passed to server ,then can i use constructors to check & validate this ?

Ex :

```
Class Cl_Controller extends Ci_controller
{
  function __construct()
 {
    //loading libraries,models,helpers etc...

    if (isset($this->input->get_post("CSRF_TOKEN")) || _another_condition_)
    {
        // The CSRF TOKEN is invalid or null ,the action cannot be done...
    }
 }
 function register()
 {
  //some codes...
 } 
 function delete_user()
 {
   //some codes
 }
}
```

Is it possible to do some thing link this ?

Please suggest me some good ideas & usual practices.

Thank you.

Comment: [CSRF Prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention)

Comment: [CodeIgniter CSRF Protection With Ajax](http://ericlbarnes.com/post/10728867961/codeigniter-csrf-protection-with-ajax) may be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my ajax calls I usually perform two checks;

Make sure it is an ajax request, using a small helper file.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('ajax_check')) {
    /**
     * Check AJAX
     * 
     * Checks to see if you (or the royal I) are dealing with an AJAX call.
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    function ajax_check() {
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            show_404();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('ajax_response')) {
    /**
     * JSON Response Wrapper
     * 
     * Wraps up any data nicely for sending back to an ajax call
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    function ajax_response($status, $data) {
        if (!is_array($data)) {
            $data = array();
        }
        // Set the JSON header appropriately
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        // Echo out the array into json
        echo json_encode(array_merge(array('status' => $status), $data));
        exit;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('ajax_force_fail')) {
    /**
     * Force AJAX Failure
     * 
     * If you ever need to, force an AJAX to fail
     */
    function ajax_force_fail() {
        $_ci =& get_instance();
        $_ci->output->set_status_header(500);
    }
}
```

Usage like;

```
public function some_function() {
    $this->load->helper('ajax');
    ajax_check();

    try {
        // do something
        ajax_response('success', array('data' => $some_var));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        ajax_response('failure', array('data' => $e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

And a similar approach to xsrf.
File:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('xsrf_get_token')) {
    /**
     * Get XSRF Token
     * 
     * Returns a token that exists for one request that verifies that
     * the action was executed by the person that requested it
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    function xsrf_get_token() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        if ($ci->session->userdata('xsrf_hash')) {
            $token = $ci->session->userdata('xsrf_hash');
        } else {
            // Generate the token
            $token = sha1(microtime().$ci->uri->uri_string());
            // Set it in the session
            $ci->session->set_userdata('xsrf_hash', $token);
        }

        //Return it
        return $token;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('xsrf_get_token_field')) {
    /**
     * Get XSRF Token Field
     * 
     * Returns an xhtml form element to include xsrf token.
     * You can specify the id/name attribute of the input.
     * Has a dependancy to get_xsrf_token().
     *
     * @param   string  The id/name to be used
     * @return  string
     */
    function xsrf_get_token_field($name='auth_token') {
        return '<input type="hidden" id="'.$name.'" name="'.$name.'" value="' .xsrf_get_token(). '" />';
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('xsrf_delete_token')) {
    /**
     * Delete XSRF Token
     * 
     * Deletes the xsrf token
     *
     * @return  boolean
     */
    function xsrf_delete_token() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        if ($ci->session->userdata('xsrf_hash')) {
            $ci->session->unset_userdata('xsrf_hash');
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('xsrf_check_token')) {
    /**
     * Get XSRF Token Field
     * 
     * Checks that the token is still valid, returns true if so. 
     * Deletes old token after valid or fail.
     * Has a dependacy to xsrf_delete_token()
     *
     * @param   string  The challenge token
     * @return  boolean
     */
    function xsrf_check_token($challenge_token) {
        // CI
        $ci =& get_instance();
        // Get the stored token
        $token = $ci->session->userdata('xsrf_hash');
        // Delete the old token
        xsrf_delete_token();
        // Returns if the token is the right token
        return ($token == $challenge_token);
    }
}
```

Usage (controller);

```
public function some_other_function() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_check_token');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE ) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // something else
    }
}

// callback function
public function check_token($val) {
    if (xsrf_check_token($val) == TRUE) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_token', 'Oops');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

In view;

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php echo xsrf_get_token_field(); ?>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: In the view, you'd have to echo the xsrf_get_token_field() since it returns the html, doesn't directly echo it.

Comment: my bad, have changed the answer.

Comment: This is good,But i cant directy use php codes on my view files ,because its generated by java script[some parts].

Comment: You could add an ajax call to your js to get the xsrf token, using xsrf_get_token()

Comment: Or you could save the token somewhere in the HTML document, and then read it from there when you generate the part of the view with javascript. Perhaps put it in the <head> or maybe as a hidden input somewhere in your footer?